# Data science Pandas CSV

Tags: csv, pandas

I have a csv file with 1461 attributes. I want to load it into a pandas data frame. The problem is, many rows do not have values for trailing consecutive columns. So pandas gives parsing error due to irregular length. How to put missing values for the leading columns for once and load the csv file into the data frame?

Edit1
We can see that the data set csv file is as follows

`a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i"""
1,2,4,5
1,0,9,8,7,6,5,4,7
1,3,5,6,7
6,7,8,8,9,4,5,3,5"""`

I want a pandas data frame like below

```
"""a b c d e f g h i
   1 2 4 5 ? ? ? ? ?
   1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 7
   1 3 5 6 7 ? ? ? ?
   6 7 8 8 9 4 5 3 5"""
```

NaN in place of ? can be ok

we don't have enough commas unequal length problem.

Comment: Can you show us the error trace ?

Comment: This sounds like you need to preprocess the file outside of pandas.

Comment: can you give some file sample - 10 rows with irregular lengths? Also are separators missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use parameter `names` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for column names by `range` (if attributes are columns):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
a,v
c,v,f,r
b,g
y"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
#in real data change 4 to 1461
names = range(4)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), names=names)
print (df)
   0    1    2    3
0  a    v  NaN  NaN
1  c    v    f    r
2  b    g  NaN  NaN
3  y  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

EDIT:

```
temp=u"""a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
1,2,4,5
1,0,9,8,7,6,5,4,7
1,3,5,6,7
6,7,8,8,9,4,5,3,5"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)
   a  b  c  d    e    f    g    h    i
0  1  2  4  5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  1  0  9  8  7.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  7.0
2  1  3  5  6  7.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  6  7  8  8  9.0  4.0  5.0  3.0  5.0
```

Comment: As far as I understand his question he is talking about leading empty columns, not trailing ones. I think for leading ones he needs to read the file normally, count the separators, and then append the appropriate number of them to the start of each line.

Comment: @Khris - hmmm, thank you for comment. But it seems some separators are missing, so values cannot matched right columns and get parse errors. But without data it is hard answer.

Comment: the error is gone but it is treating all the values as NaN and does not import all the rows. and the data is numeric do i convert it to numbers. Sorry I meant trailing. sorry floats is ok. all i want is to not get NaN for a number. your solution is correct but it seems to be for strings how can we make it work for floats?

Comment: [`read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has options to tinker with nan values.

Comment: @Khris yep, but the original csv file just has blank values. usually we have '?' to denote missing values. the data set just has blanks and nothing to denote missing values.

Comment: @Khriss :) Yeap I think of writing an automation for it ;) now to put some missing value designator

Comment: Hmmm, I think it works for float same. For replace some char to `NaN` check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#na-values - so need add parameters `keep_default_na=False, na_values=["?"]`

Comment: @jezrael how do I convert your solution to extract floating point values? your solution works perfect for strings. Cause we don't have commas and the length of the lines is variable.

Comment: @NiranjanAgnihotri - extract? I dont understand. Can you explain more or better add some sample of data with desired output to question? Thank you.

Comment: @jezrael i edited the question you can observe assume letters as column names. some rows have 4 values some have values for all columns my problems is for the row who don't have all values don't have enough commas that's the pain :)

Comment: @NiranjanAgnihotri - but then there isno problem, because it parse correctly. Or you need different output? Please check edited answer.